# SQL 2008 Update working database structure from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-structures, sql-server-2008-r2

sorry if this seams a daft question but:

I have a development database that I've been working on and updating.
I also have a live database at a external site.

I have changed the development database considerably, adding tables and fields etc.

Is there away of updating the structure of the live database to match my development one, without losing data in the live.

Regards
Graham

Comment: You can use DB compare tool to find out the difference or you can generate the scripts of DB objects and compare the files in visual studio to find out the differences

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but where would I fond the DB compare tool? Will it make a script I can run on the live server and update the structure?

Comment: You can use Db comparer it's frr version..ther are other paid tools available which you can google it.. Download db comparer from this link http://dbcomparer.com/

Comment: another free tool https://github.com/OpenDBDiff/OpenDBDiff

Comment: I *think* SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) can also do this through Visual Studio - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx). You can use the Community edition if you don't want to pay and don't already have VS.

Comment: Just adding on to @3N1GM4. Here is the link for SSDT - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt . This is a free edition from Microsoft that can support from SQL Server 2005 - SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however these are comparing and the other database is miles away from where I am with no way off accessing it unless I go there. What I need is a update script made from my database, that I can take over and run to change the other database.

Comment: If you can't access the production DB to compare it to your dev DB, how can a script to apply the delta of differences to production ever be automatically generated? You most likely need to either establish connectivity between the two DBs, or take a backup of production when you're there and bring it back to compare to your dev DB. Unless anyone else can think of another way, those are the only options I can see.